# AngularJS, injecting service into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I just began to work with angularJS and started to divide my main.js into several own files. My structure is as follows:

app.js

index.html

/service/service1

/controller/cont1

My question is how to inject the service into the controller.

The App:

```
angular.module('App',['ngDragDrop']);
```

The service:

```
angular.module('App')
   .factory('service1',function()
{...}
```

I tried to load the service1 into cont1 by injecting

```
angular.module('App')
    .controller('cont1', cont1);

cont1.$inject=['$scope', 'service1']; 

function cont1($scope, service1) {
    $scope.we=service1.doSomething(); 
}
```

but it never worked.

Finally I added the script of service1 into my index.html file, just before I load the controller file and it worked fine.

Do I have to add every service I want to use somewhere in my app into the index file? Is there no other way? To me it seems somehow dumb if I have tons of script tags in my index.html

Greetz and thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't include the script, there's no way that the browser will know to fetch it so yes, that's a requirement.  Typically people will either concatenate their JS into one large file or several files to minimize the number of inclusions needed and the number of round trips required.  Task runners like Grunt or Gulp help with this immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your index.html will contain all your scripts references. You can get fancy and create a task that will minify and combine all your js file into one then only have only 1 file referenced. For debugging purposes, you wanna have access to all your js files in case you want set breakpoints and debug

Comment: Aye, I forgot about minifing. Thanks for pointing it out!   I just wanted to make sure I didnt oversaw something fundamental in Angular, but when this is the way to go I'm fine. Its obvious I have to load the script, just the idea of having like (too many) script tags scared me. Minifing solves that when I'm done developing